# Blender 2.8 which processes fastest, skinning or bone constraint?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

Just out of curiosity so as not to slow down Blender needlessly:
When rigging solid parts of a character like a robot, which will run fastest:
Mesh that is bone constrained to the bone ?
Mesh that is skinned to the bone ?

I know it probably won't matter for one character but say I start getting a large cast in one scene like 15 characters ?

I guess I'm curious which setup processes the most effectively ?

Comment: I don't know what the official word is, but it strikes me as reasonable to assume that since the constraint works at the Object level, and the bind at the Object Data level, that the former would be less resource intensive than the latter. But who knows? It may not work like one would expect.

Comment: I thought that as well, but I know in game development we tend to bind rigid meshes to the bones rather than constrain so that would suggest skinning is fastest ? It may also vary with the methods used in different software or engine ? so I guess I'm curious how Blender handles the two options and which is fastest ?